# PHP preg_replace - Replace text part but not too soon

Tags: php, preg-replace

Using:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[\[(.*?)SPACE(.*?)\]\]/im",'$2',$text);
```

for cleaning and get **wordtwo**

```
$text = '..text.. [[wordoneSPACE**wordtwo**]] ..moretext..';
```

but fails if text has [[ before

```
$text = '.. [[ ..text(not to cut).. [[wordoneSPACE**wordtwo**]] ..moretext..';
```

how can I limit to only where I have only the SPACE word?

Comment: What format is it ? There could be parsers that already exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be no `[` and `]` inside the `[[...]]` you may use

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[\[([^][]*)SPACE([^][]*)]]/i",'$2',$text);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H38s5w/1). `[^][]` negated character class will only match a char other than `[` and `]` and won't cross the `[[...]]` border.

Otherwise, use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
$text = preg_replace("/\[\[((?:(?!\[{2}).)*?)SPACE(.*?)]]/is",'$2',$text);
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/H38s5w/2).

The `(?:(?!\[{2}).)*?` pattern will match any char, 0 or more repetitions but as few as possible, that does not start `[[` char sequence, and won't cross the next entity `[[` border.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be using [possessive quantifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

In the first group you could use a negated character class to match any characters except square brackets or an S if it is followed by SPACE.

```
\[\[([^][S]++(?:S(?!PACE)|[^][S]+)*+)SPACE([^][]++)\]\]
```

In parts

- `\[\[` Match `[[`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^][S]++` Match 1+ times any char except S, ] or [
  - `(?:` Non capturing group

    - `S(?!PACE)` Match either an S not followed by PACE
    - `|` Or
    - `[^][S]+` Match 1+ times any char except S, ] or [
  - `)*+` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group 1
- `SPACE` Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `[^][]++` Match 1+ times any char except `]` or `[`
- `)` Close group
- `\]\]` Match `]]`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1abhiL/1)